# SQL statement - use avg and count together but in different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume we have the table as follows,

```
 id  Col-1   Col-2              
  A   1     some text           
  B   0     some other text    
  C   3     
...
```

Take the table above as example, I want to build one SQL statement which would output the result: 2, 2.

The first value is the avg of all col-1 values except for 0, that is (1+3)/2 = 2. (If 0 is counted, then the result would be (1+0+3)/3 = 1, which is not what I want.)

The second value is the total number of all col-2 that is not empty. So the value is 2.

P.S, I know how to create them separately. What I prefer is to create only 1 statement to get both results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first you can use `NULLIF` as null values are ignored in aggregations such as `AVG`.

For the second I assume you want to only count values not NULL or empty string.

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(Col1, 0)),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Col2 <> '' THEN 1 END)
FROM   T
```

Comment: Tested it and it works perfectly. More importantly, this is easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when col1 <> 0 then col1 end) as avg_not_zero,
       count(col2) as num_not_empty
from table t;
```

As a note:  `0` does not mean that the value is empty.  Often `NULL` is used for this purpose in SQL, although strictly speaking, `NULL` means an unknown value.

Note:  If "empty" could mean the empty string instead of `NULL`:

```
select avg(case when col1 <> 0 then col1 end) as avg_not_zero,
       count(nullif(col2, '')) as num_not_empty
from table t;
```